# Encoding Directory and File names into an Url

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I'm implementing a classic file and directory navigation system. I need exaclty what version control system (like github or bitbucket) have. I have a hierarchy that represents files and folders and and what the url route to match the current folder like this `Entity/Details/entity1/rootFoler/otherFolder`. In this url `Entity/Details/entity1` is fixed when navigating into folders of `entity1`. The rest of the url should match the path from the root folder to current folder.

The thing is that files and folders can have names that cannot be displayed in the url. I tried to use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` to encode those names and `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode` to get them back. But NTFS file system allows a folder to be named `%20` and when I use `UrlPathEncode` is just returns `%20` and the end when I use `UrlDecode` it gives me an empty string.

I need a way of converting folder names to some string that can be displayed in the url and then convert them back to the original string. I looked for an answer on Internet but couldn't find the key for the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Try string replace all % with %25 before using URL encoding.

Comment: @Quintium Great. That solved the conflict with `%` character. But now I wonder if there are more conflictive characters that `UrlPathEncode ` cannot handle.

Comment: I believe you should be good with just that change.